# Is it possible to associate entities in different models?

Tags: entity-framework

We have one DB with many tables. We decided to create different models instead of just one containing all the tables.

We'd now need to associate an Entity (table) in ModelA with an Entity (table) in ModelB. Obviously at DB level this is possible (a simple foreign key) but it looks like it is not at model level.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is composed of one big model with many tables and relationships

But in your application if you are going to split it into two models then there is a lot of chance of having "Entities" that will be needed in different models.

You can create two different entities instead each representing what is needed from the table in each particular model and map each entity to the same table in Entity Framework

See the image below

[image: Two models, one database]

The black boxes are your tables, the red and blue are your entites.
As you can see the whole database is related but your ModelA includes only some fields on the common table, while Model B includes its own set of fields from the common table.